# $2\cos ^5x-4\sin ^2x \cos^3x$ to $6\cos ^5x-4\cos ^3x$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to simplify $2\cos ^5x-4\sin ^2x \cos^3x$ to $6\cos ^5x-4\cos ^3x$?

I've tried to factorise it but I got $6\cos^5x-2$.

Comment: Just substitute $\sin ^2 x= 1-\cos^2 x$ in the first expression.

Comment: Hint: $\cos^2x +\sin^2x=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:$sin^2 x + cos^2x=1$

Use it in the first equation to replace $sin^2x$.

See below only if you fail to understand the hint.

$2cos^5x-4cos^3x(1-cos^x)$

$=2cos^5x-4cos^3x+4cos^5x$

$=6cos^5x-4cos^3x$